# Updating list of POJOs using Java Stream API

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have the following POJO:

```
public class Order {
  private String name;
  private String status;
  private BigDecimal total;

  // getters, setters and ctors down here

}
```

I am looping through a `List<Order>` and trying to update all their `status` fields to a value of `"ORDERED"`. The *old* (pre Streaming API) way of doing this was:

```
for (Order order : orders) {
  order.setStatus("ORDERED");
}
```

I'm trying to figure out the Java 8 ("Streaming") way of accomplishing the same thing. My best attempt thus far:

```
orders.stream().map(order -> order.setStatus("H"));
```

Produces a compiler error:

> "*Incompatible types. Required List but 'map' was inferred to Stream: no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Stream conforms to List*"

**Any ideas where I'm going awry?**

Comment: Don't use streams for mutating the object while streaming the collection.

Comment: You want to perform an action **for each** element, so what made you decide for trying `map` instead of one of [the other stream operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#t0), e.g. `forEach`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `forEach`:

```
orders.forEach(order -> order.setStatus("H"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to use `Stream.map()` because it requires a return value which replaces the original value in the stream. You are also missing a terminal operation in your stream, so even if you fix that by returning the original value it wont work. `Stream.forEach()` is a terminal operation you can use for this.

To update each object in your list you can just use `orders.forEach()`. This is the same as `orders.stream().forEach()`.

```
orders.forEach(o -> o.setStatus("H"));
```

If you want to update only some values of your List you can use `Stream.filter()` before:

```
orders.stream()
        .filter(o -> "ABC".equals(o.getName())
        .forEach(o -> o.setStatus("H"));
```